# Using file locks with rsync

Tags: rsync

From the rsync manual documentation I see that by using the option rsync-path, it is possible to specify what program is to be run on the remote machine to start up rsync. In particular, the program could be a wrapper script which calls the actual rsync command in the middle, but which does some actions before and/or after the rsync invocation. One possible interesting use would be to acquire/release a lock (e.g., a flock), so that the operations of rsync at the remote end could be co-ordinated with another process at the far end which is contending for write access to the same files. There could be multiple rsync processes simultaneously holding the shared lock (I am aware of potential for starvation but am not concerned about that right now). The 'writer' process I'm dealing with would just be changing a few hard-links, so it would not block the rsync process for any significant lengh of time.

I have looked at other co-ordination approaches, e.g., implementing a custom remote locking protocol between the client and server, but they all involve more development work and/or are unsatisfactory for other reasons, which is why I am interested in the wrapper/(f)lock approach.

My questions are:

1) Is this a reasonable way to solve the problem of co-ordinating rsync 'readers' with another, 'writer' process accessing the same directory?

2) Can you also put a wrapper around rsync when using the inetd (or xinetd) daemon approach to running rsync, by adding a line something like the following to /etc/inetd.conf (as per the rsyncd.conf man page):

rsync   stream  tcp     nowait  root   /usr/bin/rsync rsyncd --daemon

but replacing /usr/bin/rsync with the path to your rsync-lookalike wrapper, which in this case would be a C/C++ -code program which seizes a lock, forks off rsync, waits for rsync to complete, then releases the lock.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: I don't see any good reason why it won't be possible...

Comment: Thanks for input, Mali. In looking around the web I have seen quite a few questions where people have been asking how to co-ordinate rsync with other processes accessing the same directory. There have been responses to those questions suggesting use flock etc. but they are at the client end (i.e., where the application  knows when rsync is going to be called, so can call flock). I haven't seen anything elsewhere about how to co-ordinate the server end, where the application doesn't know when rsync is being invoked, hence the 'wrapper' approach.

Comment: I also asked on the rsync mailing list and it seems it may also be possible to use the rsync "pre-xfer exec" and "post-xfer exec" scripts and the $RSYNC_PID env var, however I would need to look further into that. In a nutshell, however, it sounds like there is a number of viable options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments to the original post, it is indeed feasible to use wrapper approach to implement (f)locks around rsync at the server end.

Answer (score 1):

One potential catch with the wrapper approach: the remote process seems to be called with extra arguments, which are appended to whatever command line you specify with --rsync-path.  So if you need to pass arguments something like the following style is needed.

```
#! /bin/sh

lock_target=$1
shift

if ! lockfile ${lock_target}.lock ; then exit 1 ; fi

trap "rm  -f ${lock_target}.lock" EXIT HUP TERM INT

/usr/bin/rsync "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the question and the comments. Armed with your ideas I solved it (for me) using --rsync-path but without any wrapper scrips on the remote host, simply by putting all payload script into --rsync-path, with a few tricks.

This particular example uses rsync to pull data from remote host while holding a flock on the remote host, e.g. remote host dumps data periodically while also holding a flock, so dump and pull must not be interleaved.

Points to note

- **rsync will append its arguments to the end of whatever command you specify in "--rsync-path"**, so command needs to cope with that, and for that I rely on bash shell features on both pulling and remote hosts.
- any pre and post processing on remote host must not write to STDOUT because that will corrupt rsync protocol and rsync will bail. Any error output should go to STDERR and it will turn up on pulling host as rsync STDERR output. This is why '1>&2' in all the error handling.
- this probably relies on remote command spawned by rsync to run by bash because I think the good old sh does not support arrays. This works for me between RHEL7 boxes. Possible work around proposed at the end.

With that in mind, here is my simplified **concept only** rehash (I've not run this particular script, my full solution has extra layers that distract attention from the main point).

The script on the pulling host:

```
#!/bin/bash

function rsync_wrap() {
  {
    flock --exclusive --timeout ${LOCK_TIMEOUT} 100 || {
      echo "Failed to lock: ${LOCK_TIMEOUT}" 1>&2
      return 1
    }

    # call real rsync with original arguments
    rsync "$@"

    exit_code=$?

    if [ ${exit_code} -eq 0 ]; then
      # Do clean up when success
      # rm -f "${LOCK_FILE}"
      # rm -rf /eg/purge/data
    else
      # Do clean up when failed
    fi

    # Note, return is important, do not let it fall out
    return ${exit_code}

  } 100<"${LOCK_FILE}"

  echo "Failed to open lock file: ${LOCK_FILE}" 1>&2
  return 1
}

# Define vars
LOCK_FILE=/var/somedir/name.lock; # or /dev/shm/name.lock
LOCK_TIMEOUT=600; #in seconds

# Build remote command, define vars and functions inside the command
remote_cmd="
  # this approach deals with crazy chars in variables and function code
  $( declare -p LOCK_FILE )
  $( declare -p LOCK_TIMEOUT )
  $( declare -f rsync_wrap )

  rsync_wrap "

local_cmd=(
  rsync
  -a
  --rsync-path="${remote_cmd}"
  # I want to handle network timeouts in SSH, not in rsync,
  # because rsync does not know that waiting for lock is expected
  -e "ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 -o ServerAliveInterval=30 ${IDENTITY_FILE:+ -i '${IDENTITY_FILE}'}"
  /remote/source/path
  /local/destination/path/
)

# Do it
"${local_cmd[@]}"
```

If remote side executes --rsync-path in something other than bash then **maybe** the whole remote command could be wrapped in something like:

```
local_cmd="bash -c '${local_cmd//\'/\'\\\'\'}'"
```